# CSS resize property not working on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, html, ios5

Today I tried to resize a `<div>` using CSS. It works in desktop browsers like Safari, Firefox & Chrome, but it’s not working on iPad.

I want to implement resizing of `<div>` without using JavaScript. With the `resize` CSS property, the user can simply drag `<div>`s to resize.

According to Apple’s own documentation, [`resize` is supported on iOS since version 1](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/resize), but I can’t see how to resize the `<div>` on iOS.

http://jsfiddle.net/dQuX7/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flexbox resize</title>
    <style>
    section {
        width: 800px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
    }
    div.left, div.right {
        outline: solid 1px #ccc;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div.left {
        width: 20%;
        resize: both;

    }
    div.right {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -moz-box-flex: 1;
        box-flex: 1;
    }
</style> 
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="left"> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        </div> 
        <div class="right"> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: css support on ios is quite poor. You should start by upgrading to ios5 which updated mobile safari quite a lot. You should also note that safari and mobile safari are not the same browser at all. It would be comparing IE7 with Chrome16. The docs you linked is well off. It looks like a desktop safari only resource. `position: fixed` was added (poorly) in ios5 while the docs mention it is supported since ios1.

Comment: @Ben: I’ve checked on iOS5, and it doesn’t seem to support `resize`. Good spot on the documentation’s stance on `position:fixed` — I’ve noticed other places where it’s inaccurate too. I’m not sure I agree that Mobile Safari’s CSS support is “quite poor” though. I think `position:fixed` was intentionally left out to avoid the risk of web apps pretending to be native apps, and it’s not surprising that `resize` isn’t supported yet. (It took Apple 3 versions to get a good interface for text selection.)

Comment: @Ben: aside from CSS features that conflict with iOS’s limitations, Mobile Safari has pretty full CSS support, and seems much closer to desktop Safari than IE7 does to Chrome 16.

Comment: It's not difficult to imagine that implementing resize would not be trivial in a touch interface.

Comment: @DuncanBabbage: yeah, on desktop the interface (in WebKit at least) is the little grab triangle on the bottom right-hand corner of the element. I’ve no idea how it would look or work on iOS — I’m sure they’d want to make it a system-wide thing like text selection, and I can’t think of a resize interface that’s currently used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `resize` property isn‘t supported on the iPad, then I’m afraid you’re stuck — there isn’t any other non-JavaScript way to allow the user to resize an HTML element.

(Note that `resize` doesn’t work on Internet Explorer or Opera either.)

Comment: As I can see on the apple developer library I found resize is supported in ios  
[link]
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html
[/link]

I think I am missing something..

Comment: True. Thing is, I can’t imagine what interface Safari on iOS would offer to allow the user to resize such an element. I’ve got a couple of test cases for `resize` for a site I’m launching soon. I’ve tried them with an iPad and and iPhone on iOS5, and I can’t figure out any gesture that lets me resize the HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

If you reconsider using Javascript, you can use jQuery UI [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), since you are still stuck even with jQuery UI when it comes to iOS.