# Why `resize` property for textarea element not working on Safari ipad?

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

Why `resize` CSS property not working for `<textarea>` on the Safari iPad? On desktop browsers, it's working fine. I have searched every forum for an answer but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443209/css-resize-property-not-working-on-ipad#answer-8443337

Comment: @RobinHood in that answer says it's not supported on iPad. But is there any alternative solution for this? and is there any particular reason for Safari not supporting it?